# OS like behavior when edditing a Tree item!

Tags: apache-flex, mouseevent, itemrenderer

I have a Tree Control inside my Flex Application which I want to edit on a doubleclick on a tree item. I found the properties doubleClickEnabled="true", doubleClick="startEditMode()", and editable="true". With these functions I can detect a double click and I can change the editable property to true based on a double click.

The problem is that after I double clicked on a Item i have to click once more to really enter the edit mode. That doesn't seem to be intuitive at all...

Somebody came up with the solution to make a additional click programaticaly:

```
clickedItemRenderer.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

The problem I have is to get the clickedItemRenderer out of the doubleclick event (MouseEvent). How can I do that? Is there a other solution tho simply enter the edit mode by double click on the tree object?

Thanks for any hints!
Markus

Comment: This article originally posted by @Thomas answered OP's question: http://www.sephiroth.it/weblog/archives/2009/12/flex_3_tree_double-click_to_edit.php